# How to compile thrust and c++ project?

Tags: c++, compilation, cuda, thrust

I got big problems about the compile when I want to use thrust and c++ meanwhile.

Here is the project structure(just a test project):

**sortbase.h**

```
#include<iostream>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
using namespace std;

template<class T>
class SortBase
{
public:
        void Init()
        {
        }
        void resize(const int &x)
        {
                CV.resize(x);
                cout<<"resize succeed!"<<endl;
        }
private: 
        thrust::device_vector<T> CV;
};
```

**sorter.h**

```
#ifndef __SORTER_H__
#define __SORTER_H__
#include <iostream>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include "sortbase.h"
using namespace std;

template<class T>
void ttest()
{cout<<"tttttttttttttttt";cout<<endl;}
        template<class KEY>
        class Sorter
        {
        public:
                Sorter():CV(NULL)
                {
                        CV=new SortBase<KEY>();
                }
                ~Sorter()
                {
                        if (CV!=NULL)
                        {
                                delete CV;
                                CV=NULL;
                        }
                }
                __host__ __device__
                virtual bool operator()(const KEY& x,const KEY& y)const
                {
                        return (x<y);
                }
                void test()
                {
                        //ttest<KEY>();
                        resize(5);
                }
        private:
                void resize(const int &x)
                {
                        CV->resize(x);
                        cout<<"resize: "<<x<<endl;
                }
        private:
                SortBase<KEY> *CV;
        };

#endif
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "include/sorter.cu"
using namespace std;

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
        Sorter<int> *sorter=new Sorter<int>();
        sorter->test();
        return 0;
}
```

What I do like this:

```
nvcc -c sorter.cu
g++ -c main.cpp -I/usr/local/cuda/include
g++ sorter.o main.o -o sorter
```

but the second step gives the error message, a lot of warning and error message.
who can help me?
some warning and error message like these:

```
/usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/device/cuda/for_each.inl: In function \u2018RandomAccessIterator thrust::detail::device::cuda::for_each_n(RandomAccessIterator, Size, UnaryFunction) [with RandomAccessIterator = thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<int> >, Size = long unsigned int, UnaryFunction = thrust::detail::generate_functor<thrust::detail::fill_functor<int> >]\u2019:
/usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/device/dispatch/for_each.h:56:   instantiated from \u2018RandomAccessIterator thrust::detail::device::dispatch::for_each_n(RandomAccessIterator, Size, UnaryFunction, thrust::detail::cuda_device_space_tag) [with RandomAccessIterator = thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<int> >, Size = long unsigned int, UnaryFunction = thrust::detail::generate_functor<thrust::detail::fill_functor<int> >]\u2019
/usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/device/for_each.inl:43:   instantiated from \u2018OutputIterator thrust::detail::device::for_each_n(OutputIterator, Size, UnaryFunction) [with OutputIterator = thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<int> >, Size = long unsigned int, UnaryFunction = thrust::detail::generate_functor<thrust::detail::fill_functor<int> >]\u2019
/usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/dispatch/for_each.h:84:   instantiated from \u2018OutputIterator thrust::detail::dispatch::for_each_n(OutputIterator, Size, UnaryFunction, thrust::device_space_tag) [with OutputIterator = thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<int> >, Size = long unsigned int, UnaryFunction = thrust::detail::generate_functor<thrust::detail::fill_functor<int> >]\u2019
/usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/for_each.inl:41:   instantiated from \u2018OutputIterator thrust::detail::for_each_n(OutputIterator, Size, UnaryFunction) [with OutputIterator = thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<int> >, Size = long unsigned int, UnaryFunction = thrust::detail::generate_functor<thrust::detail::fill_functor<int> >]\u2019
/usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/generate.inl:47:   instantiated from \u2018OutputIterator thrust::generate_n(OutputIterator, Size, Generator) [with OutputIterator = thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<int> >, Size = long unsigned int, Generator = thrust::detail::fill_functor<int>]\u2019
/usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/device/cuda/fill.inl:87:   instantiated from \u2018OutputIterator thrust::detail::device::cuda::detail::fill_n(OutputIterator, Size, const T&, thrust::detail::false_type) [with OutputIterator = thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<int> >, Size = long unsigned int, T = int]\u2019
/usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/device/cuda/fill.inl:117:   instantiated from \u2018OutputIterator thrust::detail::device::cuda::detail::fill_n(OutputIterator, Size, const T&, thrust::detail::true_type) [with OutputIterator = thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<int> >, Size = long unsigned int, T = int]\u2019
/usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/device/cuda/fill.inl:138:   instantiated from \u2018OutputIterator thrust::detail::device::cuda::fill_n(OutputIterator, Size, const T&) [with OutputIterator = thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<int> >, Size = long unsigned int, T = int]\u2019
/usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/device/dispatch/fill.h:57:   instantiated from \u2018OutputIterator thrust::detail::device::dispatch::fill_n(OutputIterator, Size, const T&, thrust::detail::cuda_device_space_tag) [with OutputIterator = thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<int> >, Size = long unsigned int, T = int]\u2019
/usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/device/fill.inl:47:   instantiated from \u2018OutputIterator thrust::detail::device::fill_n(OutputIterator, Size, const T&) [with OutputIterator = thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<int> >, Size = long unsigned int, T = int]\u2019
/usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/dispatch/fill.h:76:   instantiated from \u2018OutputIterator thrust::detail::dispatch::fill_n(OutputIterator, Size, const T&, thrust::device_space_tag) [with OutputIterator = thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<int> >, Size = long unsigned int, T = int]\u2019
/usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/fill.inl:46:   instantiated from \u2018OutputIterator thrust::fill_n(OutputIterator, Size, const T&) [with OutputIterator = thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<int> >, Size = long unsigned int, T = int]\u2019
/usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/vector_base.inl:757:   instantiated from \u2018void thrust::detail::vector_base<T, Alloc>::fill_insert(typename thrust::detail::contiguous_storage<T, Alloc>::iterator, typename thrust::detail::contiguous_storage<T, Alloc>::size_type, const T&) [with T = int, Alloc = thrust::device_malloc_allocator<int>]\u2019
/usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/vector_base.inl:561:   instantiated from \u2018void thrust::detail::vector_base<T, Alloc>::insert(typename thrust::detail::contiguous_storage<T, Alloc>::iterator, typename thrust::detail::contiguous_storage<T, Alloc>::size_type, const T&) [with T = int, Alloc = thrust::device_malloc_allocator<int>]\u2019
/usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/vector_base.inl:223:   instantiated from \u2018void thrust::detail::vector_base<T, Alloc>::resize(typename thrust::detail::contiguous_storage<T, Alloc>::size_type, typename thrust::detail::contiguous_storage<T, Alloc>::value_type) [with T = int, Alloc = thrust::device_malloc_allocator<int>]\u2019

include/sortbase.h:14:   instantiated from void SortBase<T>::resize(const int&) [with T = int]
include/sorter.cu:40:   instantiated from void Sorter<KEY>::resize(const int&) [with KEY = int]
include/sorter.cu:35:   instantiated from void Sorter<KEY>::test() [with KEY = int]
main.cpp:9:   instantiated from here
/usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/device/cuda/for_each.inl:93: error: invalid     application of sizeof to incomplete type thrust::detail::STATIC_ASSERTION_FAILURE<false>
/usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/device/cuda/arch.h: At global scope:
/usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/device/cuda/arch.h:59: warning: inline function size_t thrust::detail::device::cuda::arch::compute_capability() used but never defined
```

Comment: Are you use thrust from CUDA installation directory?

Comment: some instantiate error and something like this: /usr/local/cuda/include/thrust/detail/device/cuda/for_each.inl:93: error: invalid application of sizeof

Comment: I use cuda4.0 and the include path is the default path

Comment: @Gang.Wang: Please edit your question to include the **exact** error message.

Comment: It's 23:11 now and I havn't solve this problem yet.

Comment: @Gang.Wang: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6978643/cuda-and-classes), and please accept my *sincere* apologies for not helping solve your problem before 23:11.

Comment: @RogerDahl thankyou very much, It's my mistake. I didn't notice the question you provide and in the sorter.h, the virtual should be deleted.

Answer (score 7):

I think that the problem is you are including your .cu file from a .cpp file.  Thrust code can only be used from .cu files, which must be compiled by NVCC, not by the host compiler g++.  So you need to move all of your Thrust and CUDA device code inside .cu files in functions that can be called from your .cpp files.

Comment: Thanks @harrism, this problem is solved, I made a stupid mistake.

Comment: Glad you got it solved. Please accept my answer if it solved your problem, or provide another answer if the solution was something else.

Answer (score 0):

Harrism is right. If you are going to compile a file using gpu, you must use `.cu` for the file and `nvcc` like:

```
nvcc -o test test.cu
```