# In CUDA, how can we call a device function in another translation unit?

Tags: cuda

I'm pretty new to CUDA. I use Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 where I don't need to worry about writing a makefile. A problem arose as I tried to call in a .cu file a device function which was declared in the .h file and defined in another .cu file. At the end of building, I received an error message:

```
1>ptxas : fatal error : Unresolved extern function '_Z22atomicAddEmulateDoublePdd'
```

This appears in both CUDA 4.2 and 5.0. I'm wondering how should I configure my MVS to avoid this error. Sorry for the nooby questions and thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: I have the exact same problem... would be interested to know if you solved it!

Comment: @KristianD'Amato: By having VS generate relocatable device code.

Comment: I have attempted that, but it didn't seem to work. Can you give me an idea how you did that exactly?

Comment: Ahhh... the little grey cells must have been asleep! I missed the instruction in the CUDA C++ tab!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CUDA 4.2 and does not support static linking so device functions must be defined in the same compilation unit. A common technique is to write the device function in a .cuh file and include it in the .cu file.

CUDA 5.0 supports a new feature called separate compilation. The CUDA 5.0 VS msbuild rules should be available in the CUDA 5.0 RC download.

Comment: Without separate compilation, I use this method to have a single definition file for both host and device; [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6978643/cuda-and-classes). How to set-up separate compilation?