# How to split class definition between multiple .cpp and .cu files?

Tags: c++, class, cuda, gpgpu, thrust

I've got a class with nested classes mixing both C++, CUDA and Thrust. I want to split member definitions across a number of files.

```
// In cls.h:
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
class cls {
    class foo {   // define in foo.cu    (include "cls.h")
        kernelWrapper();
    }
    class bar {   // define in bar.cu    (include "cls.h")
        thrust::device_vector A;
        thrustStuff();
    }
    thrust::device_vector B;
    pureCPP();      // define in cls.cpp (include "cls.h")
    moreThrust();   // define in cls.cu  (include "cls.h")
}
```

In each definition file I simply `#include "cls.h"`. However, I am currently getting an assortment of compiler errors no matter what I try, like `pureCPP was referenced but not defined`.

- I've read Thrust can only be used with `.cu` files. Because my parent class `cls` declares Thrust-type variables like `B` (and hence `#include`s `thrust/device_vector.h`), does that force all files that `#include` `cls.h` to be made into `.cu` files?
- Where do I use `extern "C"` in this case? I suppose `cls.cpp` would require all functions in `.cu` files to be wrapped in `extern "C"`, but what about `.cu` to `.cu` calls, like `moreThrust()` calling `bar::thrustStuff()`
- I've also been made aware members of classes don't work with `extern "C"`, so do I have to write an `extern "C"` wrapper function for each member function?

I'm utterly confused as to how to make this all work - what cocktail of `#include`s and `extern "C"`s do I need for each file?

Comment: you don't need extern "C" at all. That's from the old days, when all CUDA code was treated as C and not C++, so you had to be very specific about the name mangling. CUDA files are C++ now

Comment: @alrikai - but my compiler has also made it very clear that I cannot just mix calls between `.cu` and `.cpp` files willy nilly. In fact, my kernel wrappers which provide `.cpp` access to `.cu` kernels only seem to work with `extern "C"`

Comment: Are you using the latest version?

Comment: Or I'm desperate enough to rename all my `.cpp` into `.cu` files - but I still can't make it work. I get constant `function [x] referenced but not defined` errors

Comment: you shouldn't have to rename anything. Try the code in my answer and let me know if it works for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking your small example, this compiled and ran fine for me

```
/*
Inside File cls.h
*/
#pragma once
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <stdio.h>

class cls {

public:
    class foo {   // define in foo.cu    (include "cls.h")
    public:
        void kernelWrapper();
    };

    class bar {   // define in bar.cu    (include "cls.h")
        thrust::device_vector<int> A;
    public:
        void thrustStuff();
    };

public:
    void pureCPP();      // define in cls.cpp (include "cls.h")
    void moreThrust();   // define in cls.cu  (include "cls.h")

private:
    thrust::device_vector<int> B;
};

/*
Inside File foo.cu
*/
#include "cls.h"
void cls::foo::kernelWrapper()
{
    printf("kernelWrapper\n");
}

/*
Inside File bar.cu
*/
#include "cls.h"
void cls::bar::thrustStuff()
{
    printf("Thrust Stuff\n");
}

/*
Inside File cls.cpp
*/
#include "cls.h"
void cls::pureCPP()
{
    printf("pureCPP\n");
}

/*
Inside File cls.cu
*/
#include "cls.h"
void cls::moreThrust()
{
    printf("moreThrust\n");
}


/*
Inside File main.cpp
*/
#include "cls.h"
int main()
{
    cls a_class;
    a_class.pureCPP();
    a_class.moreThrust();

    cls::bar a_class_bar;
    a_class_bar.thrustStuff();

    cls::foo a_class_foo;
    a_class_foo.kernelWrapper();
}
```

Running this prints

`pureCPP`

`moreThrust`

`Thrust Stuff`

`KernelWrapper`

If anything, I'd bet that you're using an IDE and it's not compilling all of your files, so while you have your class member declaration in your header file, but it'll never find the corresponding definition. Your exact compilation commands will be different, but for me (on Linux) I used

```
nvcc -G -g -O0 -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_21 -odir "src" -M -o "src/bar.d" "../src/bar.cu"
nvcc --device-c -G -O0 -g -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_21  -x cu -o  "src/bar.o" "../src/bar.cu"

nvcc -G -g -O0 -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_21 -odir "src" -M -o "src/cls.d" "../src/cls.cu"
nvcc --device-c -G -O0 -g -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_21  -x cu -o  "src/cls.o" "../src/cls.cu"

nvcc -G -g -O0 -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_21 -odir "src" -M -o "src/foo.d" "../src/foo.cu"
nvcc --device-c -G -O0 -g -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_21  -x cu -o  "src/foo.o" "../src/foo.cu"

nvcc -G -g -O0 -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_21 -odir "src" -M -o "src/main.d" "../src/main.cpp"
nvcc -G -g -O0 --compile  -x c++ -o  "src/main.o" "../src/main.cpp"

nvcc -G -g -O0 -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_21 -odir "src" -M -o "src/clscpp.d" "../src/cls.cpp"
nvcc -G -g -O0 --compile  -x c++ -o  "src/clscpp.o" "../src/cls.cpp"

nvcc --relocatable-device-code=true -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_21 -link -o  "split_compilation"  ./src/bar.o ./src/cls.o ./src/foo.o ./src/clscpp.o ./src/main.o
```

The idea is just to compile all of your source files and link them together. For example, if I didn't compile and link the cls.cpp file, I'd get a linker error on any calls to `pureCPP`.

Also, note that if you're using actual device code, you'll have to have specify `__device__` and/or `__host__` for your member functions. See [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6978643/cuda-and-classes)

Comment: Yes, thanks. I come from C, so I was making the rookie mistake of not putting my templates or inlining them.